# Camera Not Working on ThinkPad Laptop Running Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, thinkpad, camera

When I went to join my first Zoom meeting today, I found my camera not working, but instead of the camera with a line through it icon, I see the below (on Zoom and the Windows Camera app):
[image]

- Device Manager says the device is working properly and no new driver
  is available.
- Reboot has no effect.
- There is no physical slider or other way the camera is blocked.
- I don't see any function key indicating that it would toggle the camera.
- Camera security settings are allow access
- Camera was working without any issue last week.

What am I missing?

Hardware: Lenovo ThinkPad T14s laptop

Software: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Check to see if the Camera is visibly working in Skype, and if so, uninstall Zoom (Control Panel), restart the install Zoom again.

Comment: Same result on Skype. What is that icon??

Comment: @John, he said the windows camera app does the same thing.  Still a good suggestion.. but probably won't be fruitful.    I think the camera itself (actual digital camera sensor) is on the fritz.  There are few ways for the system to know this if the camera board/module still functions.

Comment: Same result on Skype may mean a Camera hardware error.

Comment: You actual camera is probably no longer functional.  The controller board it is hooked to is probably fine (and yet worthless).  Choices?  Buy a better USB camera (laptop cameras mostly suck anyways) or get it repaired somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

check the top of the computer just above the camera. youll find a tiny slider. move it physically to the right. Viola!

Comment: The asker says *"There is no physical slider or other way the camera is blocked."*.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1134112)